# Always the 1st defined directive is working while others are not AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularJs to write a simple web application and I am facing a weird issue where the 1st defined directive is always working while others are not.

I have 3 directives defined (hostTableArea, hostGraphArea and hostSummeryArea) these are the details of those directives

```
var app = angular.module("app-directive", []);
app.directive("hostTableArea", function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        templateUrl : "/js/directive/host-table-area/host-table-area.html",
        link: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.value);
        }
    };
});

var app = angular.module("app-directive", []);
app.directive("hostGraphArea", function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            val2: '='
        },
        templateUrl : "/js/directive/host-graph-area/host-graph-area.html",
        link: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.val2);
        }
    };
});

var app = angular.module("app-directive", []);
app.directive("hostSummeryArea", function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            val3: '='
        },
        templateUrl : "/js/directive/host-summery-area/host-summery-area.html",
        link: function ($scope) {
              console.log($scope.val3);
        }
    };
});
```

I have corresponding HTML files for each directive and the HTML file is defined in the templateURL location. All the directives are used in the **index.html** page

```
<div class="tab-content area-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tableView" >
        <host-table-area data-value="'text-1'"></host-table-area>
    </div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="graphView">
        <host-graph-area data-val2="'text-2'"></host-graph-area>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="summaryView">
        <host-summery-area val3="'text-3'"></host-summery-area>
    </div>
</div>
```

And all the 3 directives are defined at the index.html page in the following order

```
<script src="/js/directive/host-summery-area/host-summery-area.js"></script>
<script src="/js/directive/host-graph-area/host-graph-area.js"></script>
<script src="/js/directive/host-table-area/host-table-area.js"></script>
```

The problem here is, the 1st defining directive will always be displayed while the other 2 does not. If the order is changed, it always displays the 1st defined directive in this list.

What is the reason and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax that you use:

```
var app = angular.module("app-directive", []);
```

creates a new module each time.Create the module once and then register each directive like this:

```
angular.module("app-directive").directive("hostTableArea", function() {};
```